# Apt-get update size too big

Tags: apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my  apt-get update fetches so large?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127522/why-are-my-apt-get-update-fetches-so-large)

Since i installed Ubuntu 12.04 Precise x64, the apt-get update size is killing me.. Since i'm stuck with a slow connection, its a pain to download ~12MB everytime. Even if I run it twice back to back, it still downloads ~12MB.

I've read some other 2-4 threads here and at ubuntuforums concerning the same issue and have already commented out the source line ( there were 2 only of these) in sources.list file but it still no joy..

Is it just because 12.04 is so new now and receiving frequent updates? Earlier when i used 10.04, there was no any problem like that...
My sources.list and apt-get update log below:

```
> # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
> 
> # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
> # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted
> 
> # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
> # newer versions of the distribution. deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
> 
> ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
> ## distribution. deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
> 
> ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
> ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
> ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe deb
> http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
> 
> ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
> ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
> ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
> ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
> ## security team. deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates
> multiverse
> 
> ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
> ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
> ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
> ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
> ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
> 
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe deb
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
> 
> ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
> ## 'partner' repository.
> ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
> ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users. deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
> # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
> 
> ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
> ## developers who want to ship their latest software. deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
> # deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports restricted main
> multiverse universe


sudo apt-get update
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                 
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Get:4 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]         
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Get:7 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [1,245 B]                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Get:9 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,268 B]                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]        
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [32.9 kB]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_IN             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages [1,273 kB]     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [8,581 B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,142 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [32.9 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [8,594 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,393 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages [8,452 B]
Get:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages [4,786 kB] 
Get:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages [119 kB] 
Get:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB]      
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B] 
Get:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB]  
Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB]  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Get:29 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [95.2 kB]
Get:30 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [757 B]
Get:31 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [27.5 kB]
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,142 B]
Get:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [96.5 kB]
Get:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [770 B]
Get:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [27.7 kB]
Get:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1,393 B]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Get:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages [559 B]
Get:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages [1,387 B]
Get:40 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:41 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [559 B]
Get:42 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:43 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [1,391 B]
Get:44 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 12.9 MB in 19min 51s (10.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```